# Is there a way to find out which port the Spark web UI is using?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

I start my Spark session in Jupyter with something like this:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = ( SparkSession
            .builder
            .appName('analysis')
            .getOrCreate() )
```

Is there a way to find out which port the web UI is using? Thanks!

Comment: I am aware that we can logon to pyspark using a specific port by the command 'pyspark  "spark.ui.port=4060"  '. I am sure, there would be some way to print the port value from this property. May be from conf.getAll() method. Can you please check.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use `uiWebUrl` property:

```
>>> spark.sparkContext.uiWebUrl
'http://some_host:4040'
```

and for example split

```
>>> spark.sparkContext.uiWebUrl.split(":")[-1]
'4040'
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I figured it out in pyspark.

```
>>> import pyspark
>>> sc = pyspark.SparkContext(appName="some_app")
>>> sc.uiWebUrl

[1]: http://localhost:4041/jobs/
```